# What does CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH do?

Tags: lvm

I know a tool `kpartx` can be used to configure multipath on system. But what does the `CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH` kernel module do? My system does not have this module compiled, and it seems the `kpartx` tools works very well. It seems they are not related, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH` is not the name of a kernel module; it's the
name of a kernel configuration option that enables the `dm_multipath`
driver, which in turn enables [multipath
i/o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_I/O) for block devices.
"Multipath I/O" means that a single device (think "disk") can be
accessed via multiple communication channels -- for example, a storage
array connected via a pair of fibre channel links.  Without the
multipath driver, each link looks like a separate device, which can
lead to confusion.  The multipath driver can present these two links
as a single device, and take care of selecting an alternative path if
one path fails.

[This document](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/DM_Multipath/index.html) from RedHat has a good discussion of multipath support under Linux.

You are correct that this has very little to do with `kpartx`.

Comment: Thanks. If `kpartx` has little to do with `dm_multipath`, then what kind of `multipath` it is talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing the reference, so it's hard to say.  The `kpartx` man page does briefly mention the multipath driver, but they're "related" in the sense that they're written by the same author and `kpartx` can operate on block devices, including those presented by the multipath driver.

Answer (score 1):

**`kpartx`** is just the component to create "*multipathed*" device entries for the partitions on a multipathed storage unit.

Imagine you insert a dual-pathed fibre channel disk with one single partition: **`udev`** discovers the disk, the "basic" kernel assigns two different devices to each of the disk's pathes (eg. `/dev/sdx` and `/dev/sdy`) , and subsequently, the one partition is visible as `/dev/sdx1` and `/dev/sdy1`.

Now, **kpartx** comes into play and creates a `/dev/mapper/<ID of the new disk>p1` device (sometimes also shown as `-part1`).

This special partition entry is what you should use for your application (instead of the dev/sd[xy]1`entries). That makes sure you access the underlying partition via the multipath module's *combined* device`/dev/mapper/`and not via just one path's`/dev/sdx1` entry.

The **kpartx** utility is so to say just a "parser" for partition tables on multipathed devices, creating multipathed device nodes just for their partitions.